# AngularJS form phone vaildation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

My  input box must accept the following combination

(123) 123-4567 or 123-123-1234

Can anyone help me out to make regular expression?

Answer (score 0):

Seems trivial :

`/^(\(\d{3}\) |\d{3}-)\d{3}-\d{4}$/`

[demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/blEnKO/1)